# В дереве найти длину путей до всех вершин

Tags: c++, дерево

Есть код,  который находит длину путей до всех листьев. Подскажите как преобразовать функцию printLeafs чтобы она находила пути до всех узлов? Или возможно это лучше реализовать в main используя printLeafs

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int val;
    node *left, *right;
    node(int i) : val(i), left(NULL), right(NULL) {};
};

node *addNode(int val)
{
    return new node(val);
}

node *addTree(node *root, int val)
{
    if (!root)
    {
        root = addNode(val);
        return root;
    }
    if (val < root->val)
    {
        if (!root->left)
        {
            root->left = addNode(val);
        }
        else
        {
            addTree(root->left, val);
        }
    }
    if (val > root->val)
    {
        if (!root->right)
        {
            root->right = addNode(val);
        }
        else
        {
            addTree(root->right, val);
        }
    }
    return root;
}

void printLeafs(node *root, int level)
{
    if (root)
    {

        printLeafs(root->left, level + 1);
        if (!root->left && !root->right)
            cout << "The path to leaf " << root->val << " is equal to " << level << endl;
        printLeafs(root->right, level + 1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int num;
    cout << "Write numbers of the tree: ";
    cin >> num;
    node *tree = NULL;
    if (num != 0)
        tree = new node(num);
    while (num != 0)
    {
        addTree(tree, num);
        cin >> num;
    }
    cout << "Leaves: " << endl;
    int level =0;
    printLeafs(tree, level);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Если правильно понял логику, то Вам надо просто в функции ```printLeafs``` оставить вывод данных, но убрать проверку на лист. Вывод должен выполняться для каждой вершины.

Comment: не думаю. при вводе дерева с узлами 1 2 3 для узла 3 выводит длину 2 хотя она 1

Comment: 1 -корень,  2 и 3 листья? или как?

Comment: да  хотя возможно у меня дерево неправильно заполняется

Comment: Если я правильно понял логику ```addTree``` , то получается, 1 - корень, 2 - его правый потомок, 3 - правый потомок 2, если вводить 1,2,3.

Comment: А если вводить 1,3,2 - то 1 - корень, 3 - узел, 2 - лист от узла 3

Comment: да вы правы, спасибо большое)